# I cant work out how to signal MACD crossovers

Tags: pine-script

Hi I am trying to work out how I colour the background when the macd crosses under, when above the 0 line and also when it crosses over when under the 0 line. What seems to be happening with my code is that it will highlight whether above or below and also seems to be highlighting quite late.

```
// Getting inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", type=input.integer, defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", type=input.integer, defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", type=input.source, defval=close)
signal_length = input(title="Signal Smoothing", type=input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input(title="Oscillator MA Type", type=input.string, defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input(title="Signal Line MA Type", type=input.string, defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", input.color, group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", input.color, group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", input.color, group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", input.color, group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", input.color, group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", input.color, group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? sma(src, fast_length) : ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? sma(src, slow_length) : ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? sma(macd, signal_length) : ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal

plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)


bullishgo= (crossover(macd, hist))
bgcolor(bullishgo ? color.aqua:na)

bearishgo= (crossunder(macd, hist))
bgcolor(bearishgo ? color.orange:na)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day Blake!

The hist plot is the difference between macd and the signal line, so if we set our cross for macd and hist, it will continue to be inconsistent where we get a signal. for example if the difference is -20, then we are waiting for the macd line to cross at -20. the difference changes on every bar as well adding to the inconsistency. What we can do is set our cross for the macd and signal line and include a above/ below zero bias. So bullish crosses are cross ups above zero, and bearish are cross downs below zero. Here is some code with those changes made. I added the hist plots and backed them off with transparency to be less aggressive, which gives us some reference to the zero line when verifying our signals.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

// Getting inputs
fast_length     = input(12,      "Fast Length",         input.integer, group="MACD Settings")
slow_length     = input(26,      "Slow Length",         input.integer, group="MACD Settings")
src             = input(close,   "Source",              input.source,  group="MACD Settings")
signal_length   = input(9,       "Signal Smoothing",    input.integer, group="MACD Settings",   maxval = 50, minval = 1)
sma_source      = input("EMA",   "Oscillator MA Type",  input.string,  group="MACD Settings",   options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal      = input("EMA",   "Signal Line MA Type", input.string,  group="MACD Settings",   options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_macd        = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ",         input.color,   group="Color Settings",  inline="MACD")
col_signal      = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ",       input.color,   group="Color Settings",  inline="Signal")
col_grow_above  = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow",        input.color,   group="Histogram",       inline="Above")
col_fall_above  = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall",                input.color,   group="Histogram",       inline="Above")
col_grow_below  = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow",          input.color,   group="Histogram",       inline="Below")
col_fall_below  = input(#FF5252, "Fall",                input.color,   group="Histogram",       inline="Below")

// Calculating

fast_ma         = sma_source == "SMA" ? sma(src,  fast_length)   : ema(src,  fast_length)
slow_ma         = sma_source == "SMA" ? sma(src,  slow_length)   : ema(src,  slow_length)
macd            = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal          = sma_signal == "SMA" ? sma(macd, signal_length) : ema(macd, signal_length)

hist            = macd - signal

bullishgo       = crossover (macd, signal) and macd > 0
bearishgo       = crossunder(macd, signal) and macd < 0

// Graphical display 

histcol         = (hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below))

bgcolor         (bullishgo ? color.new(color.aqua,   80) : na)
bgcolor         (bearishgo ? color.new(color.orange, 80) : na)

plot            (macd,   "MACD",    col_macd)
plot            (signal, "Signal",  col_signal)
plot            (hist, "Histogram"  color=color.new(histcol,70), style=plot.style_columns,)
```

Cheers brother and have a great day

Comment: HI Bjorgum, thankyou once again. I  would literally be getting nowhere without your input. Not only do you take the time to help out but you always put some theory there as well which is great for understanding the logic. I have added the script however it says "line 105: Mismatched input 'color' expecting ')'." I have tried playing with what I think would work however cant seem to understand what needs to happen with the line

Comment: whoops! sorry a couple of rogue commas in that last line. needs one after "histogram" and delete the one after columns before the last bracket. I moved style to the end and didnt check last thing!

Comment: plot            (hist, "Histogram",  color=color.new(histcol,70), style=plot.style_columns)

Comment: Thanks Bjorgum, I put a ")" in every place I could find, haha. thankyou once again, I really appreciate the quick responses.

Comment: Cheers glad I could help! Take care